# Sorted list python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I'm trying to sort a list of string in python.
This list is composed of name of files like `1.svg 2.svg ...`
The problem is when I work with `10.svg` the list become :
`1.svg 10.svg 2.svg` 
and I need `1.svg 2.svg 10.svg`
Do you know how to do that ?

Thanks,

I saw the duplicate link but I can't import natsort, maybe it needs python 3.0 no ? (I'm am working with 2.7)

Comment: So you're trying to sort the strings as if the first part were an integer?

Comment: Another option if you can't get nartsort:

Comment: x = [str(item) + '.svg' for item in sorted([int(item.split('.')[0]) for item in x])]

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '/path/svg/1'

Comment: a = ['1.svg', '2.svg', '3.svg', '10.svg']
a.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))